# Class Component should not re-render when updating state

Tags: reactjs, state

I am working on a Portfolio site that has some "Teaser Projects" appearing (in an animated way) on the home page. Each image has a project title that should appear as custom cursor when hovering the appropriate project div / image.

What should be pretty straightforward turned out to be quite complicated due to (logical) re-rendering of the component.

I set up a CodeSandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sun-b3i2d

How can I allow the Class Component to update it's state and show the appropriate cursor div (that should follow the mouse later) without re-rendering it (and making the animation play again)?

Comment: Maybe you can render a component with a transparent `div` above the animated `div` and manage the state there?

Comment: Thank you @AkshitMehra That's what I actually thought of as well but I was afraid this was too much of a quick & dirty way and not very "react-ish"

Comment: @BrandonDyer Answer to why not just use CSS: maybe the "custom cursor" depends upon the state?

Comment: Exactly, there's more going on. Sry, should've pointed that out in my question as I cleaned up those things in the Sandbox as well.